# Running bash script in another directory

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, raspberry-pi3

I know this question has been asked many times before but I have not been able to get my code working.
I am using the Raspberry Pi 3, with a CAN-BUS Shield.  As this will be going into a production environment I need the Pi setup to be nice and easy.  I have started to write a bash script so the production staff can run the script and the Pi will update and install everything it needs from the one script.
I have been following this web site https://harrisonsand.com/can-on-the-raspberry-pi/ and I have run into a problem when it comes to compiling can-utils.

I am able to clone the can-utils.git from here https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils.git
by using `sudo git clone https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils.git`
but my issues come when I need to run the `./autogen.sh` & the `./configure` as these are located in the dir can-utils.

If I run this from the Pi terminal as described on the web site, it works fine as I change dir `cd can-utils` and then just `sudo ./autogen.sh` but it isn't working when I run it in the bash script.

Below is the script I have so far, I know that most of it is commented out this is so that I can test each part as I write it and don't need to constantly download and install stuff I already have

```
#!/bin/bash

## Change Password
#printf "***********************************************************************\n"
#printf "Changing Password\n"
#echo "pi:***********" | sudo chpasswd     # Password hidden
#sleep 1
#printf "Password Changed\n"

## Update & Upgrade Pi
#printf "***********************************************************************\n"
#printf "Update & Upgrade Pi\n\n"
#sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
#sleep 1

## Upgrade dist
#printf "***********************************************************************\n"
#printf "Upgrade Dist\n\n"
#sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
#sleep 1

## Install libtools
#printf "***********************************************************************\n"
#printf "Installing libtools\n\n"
#sudo apt-get install git autoconf libtool -y
#sleep 1

## Download required files
#printf "***********************************************************************\n"
#printf "Downloading required files\n\n"
## can-utils
#sudo git clone https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils.git
#sleep 1

## Auto configure can-utils
printf "***********************************************************************\n"
printf "Auto Configure can-utils\n\n"
# Things I have tried and do not work
#(cd /c && exec /can-utils/autogen.sh)
#sudo source /can-utils/autogen.sh
#sudo ./can-utils.autogen.sh
sleep 1
```

When I try the `sudo ./can-utils.autogen.sh`in the Pi terminal the script starts to work so I think this is sort of the right command I need but then I get an error `autoreconf: 'configure.ac or 'configure.in' is required`  these files are in the can-utils dir but for some reason it can't find them.  Please can someone help me I have been searching for the answer for the last 2 days

Comment: A place to start, in the future, would be building a [mcve] -- the *shortest possible* code that demonstrates your problem. Ideally, that would be two lines -- a `git clone`, and then another trying to run `autogen`, with none of the commented-out irrelevant cruft.

Comment: And btw, you really shouldn't be using `sudo` here. It magnifies the vulnerability you're exposed to from either an attack on `git` via the hosting service, or malicious code in the base you're compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, rightly or wrongly I have ended up using `cd /home/pi/can-utils` I had thought I had tried that in the past but I think `cd ./can-utils` which didn't work.

Comment: `cd ./can-utils` will work fine if you're in the direct parent when you run it.

Answer (score -1):

sudo with script is for me, a nightmare. I just read in the man of sudo of my fedora 25:

> Running shell scripts via sudo can expose the same kernel bugs that make setuid shell scripts unsafe on some operating systems (if your OS has a /dev/fd/ directory, setuid shell scripts are generally safe).

sudo command should protect the root account to avoid to run scripts written by user to gain root privilege.

If you keep the use of sudo, my advise should to add a cd command on top of your script:

```
cd /where_everithing_is
```

to be sure to be in the right place. 
But, may be, sudo will fight again against you !